# In Jenkins, how do you rename a job using the CLI?

Tags: jenkins, command-line-interface

I've been reading [this wiki article about the Jenkins CLI](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI).  Is there a way to rename a job through the CLI?  I can't seem to find a way.  An obvious workaround would be to copy a job then delete the old one, but I'm hoping there's a more straight forward way.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the job directory under $JENKINS_HOME/jobs?  The obvious limitation is that you would only be able to do this on the server and not on any slaves.  But once you have renamed the directory, you can run the CLI with the reload-configuration command.

Comment: @Craig haven't tried, but this limitation won't work for me.

Comment: If you configure an SSH key for authentication, you could rename the job via an SSH script and have Jenkins reload configuration using the CLI afterwards.

Comment: When copying the job, do you get a copy of the artefacts as well?

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I had to rename a larger number of jobs and was hoping on the CLI. There is no dedicated rename command. I did not try to `get-job` and then push a changed version up again, maybe that would work.

I have no direct access to the Jenkins machine and thus cannot mess around on the file system, like some suggested.

I resorted to a manual approach, with some clicking - maybe this is viable workaround for others: https://.../jenkins/job/OLD-JOB-NAME/rename?newName=NEW-JOB-NAME - this will give you a "are you sure" prompt, which after confirming should rename the job.

Comment: I so wanted this to work! However on CloudBees Jenkins Enterprise 2.164.2.1-rolling there is no "rename", there is only **confirm-rename** and the ?newName parameter does not seem to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother with Jenkins' own CLI. If you just navigate to the Jenkins jobs' directory on your filesystem and rename the job using the 'mv' unix command, then refresh Jenkins it should be fine. (you may have to reload the config from the disk in the Jenkins settings if refreshing doesn't work)

Comment: Can I do all those things from a shell script?

Comment: Changing the job names is a simple 'mv' command. Restarting Jenkins can be done by shutting down its Tomcat (or whatever) container and restarting it. But reloading its config is the easiest way, which can be done on the webpage.